# Testing the matlab application

Tags: matlab, testing, functional-testing

I am doing the project in matlab. I want to test it. Is there any facility to test the matlab project online. I had .exe file for my project or is there any tool in matlab to test the project including the GUI and functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "testing the project"? Do you mean debug it?

Comment: I want to apply different automated testing techniques to my matlab application.

Comment: Do you really mean "the matlab application", in the sense of "matlab.exe"?

Comment: noooo.....i had created one app in matlab and now i generate its .exe file...now i want to apply dat application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding unit tests [MATLAB xUnit Test Framework](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846) is a good point to start.